# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tia.analysis.model'

Tags: python, import

This is line2, python code

```
import tia.analysis.talib_wrapper as talib
```

Console shows

```
  File "t10.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tia.analysis.talib_wrapper as talib
  File "/home/jholmes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tia/analysis/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tia.analysis.model import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tia.analysis.model'
```

Why is module not recognized?I have installed tia with 
pip install.

Other code from [examples](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bpsmith/tia/blob/master/examples/v3api.ipynb) makes even more crazy problems.

```
from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal
import pandas as pd

resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data('MSFT US EQUITY', ['PX_LAST', 'GICS_SECTOR_NAME', 'VOLATILITY_30D'])
resp.as_frame()
```

I got

```
  File "t11.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal
  File "/home/jholmes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tia/bbg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tia.bbg.v3api import *
  File "/home/jholmes/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tia/bbg/v3api.py", line 186
    print 'unhandled event: %s' % evt.EventType
                              ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(int 'unhandled event: %s' % evt.EventType)?
```

Just one proof that package is here

```
pip install tia
Requirement already satisfied: tia in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tia)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tia)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas->tia)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas->tia)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas->tia)
```

Comment: looks like this lib works only with python2

Comment: @Aiven I could import tia as ta,so I am not sure about that.

Comment: py2 and py3 partially compatible. `tia.__init__` may have only imports inside and it will run fine in py2 and py3 without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tia [github](https://github.com/bpsmith/tia#dependencies) page explicitly said that library compatible only with python 2.7. So I guess that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the first error it seems that you do not have the package installed but the root cause may be different.

The second error is not crazy. You are trying to use the Python2 library under Python3 which gives you an error. Could you possibly give more information about what you did? What Python version you wanted to run, etc.

If you dive into project specification and [README.md](https://github.com/bpsmith/tia) page, you can see that dependency is Python2.7

Comment: @MikiBelavista, unfortunately, not all installed packages are compatible with Python3. I had an issue when I was able to install the package but not to run it.